# How to convert NA values as NULL values when importing txt file in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to import a txt file which has NA values in some columns, which are in numeric format (double precision)

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
100 0.05    NA  11556135.4  1.22911 NA  5.19    NA  17572151.86 3.45E+08
100 0.25    25  11556135.4  1.32911 NA  5.19    NA  17572151.86 69552000
100 0.09    NA  13405172.5  1.16911 44  5.233   23  47253072.8  5.20E+08
100 0.11    NA  15434493.7  1.18911 NA  5.212   NA  55434589.68 5.25E+08
```

I am getting an error

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "NA"
> ```

this is the code that I am using to import the file.

```
copy bond FROM '~/filtered77k.txt' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER AS E'\t'
```

Comment: Use sed to preprocess the file like : `sed 's/\tNA\t/\t\t/g' <infile >outfile`

Comment: `copy bond FROM '~/filtered77k.txt' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER AS E'\t' NULL 'NA'` I used this and it worked. Thank you @ wildplasser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copy bond FROM '~/filtered77k.txt' WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER AS E'\t' NULL 'NA'` I